# mongoose uniqueness constraint not being maintained

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following user schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        validate: usernameValidator,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    }, 
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

where `usernameValidator` is just a check on max length.

For the username, I have set `unique: true`. However, if I run a test script that inserts the user with username 'test', it gets inserted every time I run the script. Here's the test script:

```
var user = new User({
    username: 'test',
    password: 'password',
});

user.save();
```

Why is it so? How do I apply the uniqueness constraint?

**Edit:**
The output of `db.users.getIndexes()` is :

```
[
  {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
      "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "dbName.users",
    "name" : "_id_"
  }
]
```

Comment: Which version of Mongoose are you using? I believe that syntax was added in 3.x.x.

Comment: @jmar777 I am using 3.8.4

Comment: That constraint is enforced by the DB.  It's worth checking to see if the index made it through to the DB.  From your mongo console, can you run `db.users.getIndexes()` and report on the output?

Comment: And did you by chance put a line with `{ autoIndex: false }` in it anywhere?

Comment: It's possible that if you already have duplicates in there the index creation is failing altogether.

Comment: @juanpaco I didn't set the `autoIndex` to false. Also, edited the question details to show the output of `db.users.getIndexes()`.

Comment: Try `User.ensureIndexes(function (err) {
  if (err) console.error(err) else console.log('User indexing successful');
});`

Comment: I had added a few users before setting the uniqueness constraint. So, could it be that the index is not updated?

Comment: The result of `getIndexes()` isn't showing a unique index on `username`, so I think that strengthens the theory that it's not being created due to existing values that violate that uniqueness.

Comment: @jmar777 When I ran that `ensureIndexes` function, I get `[MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: dbName.users.$username_1  dup key: { : "test" }]`

Comment: That is a possibility, yes.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/ gives you a way to remove the duplicates.  It will drop data though, so heads up.

Comment: You might from your mongo console also run `db.users.find()` to see the already-existing duplicates.

Comment: I dropped the duplicates and then ran the `ensureIndexes()` function and now the duplicates aren't being inserted. Although, this was just a test database,so I could afford to drop the data. However, since mongo is supposed to be schema-less, the schema might change later on. So, do I need to manually update indexes every time?

Comment: Indexes won't need to be updated unless you're they're pertaining to new properties that didn't previously exist.  Normally it's not a problem to simply create them on the fly, but in the case of creating a unique index, the existing data has to be compatible with that uniqueness.  Either you have to instruct Mongo to drop duplicates when it creates the index (as mentioned by @juanpaco), or you have to clean the data yourself.  It just doesn't make any sense for Mongo to allow the index to be created if there's already data that violates it.